# Computing product of matrix exponential with vector using Runge Kutta

Tags: matrix-exponential, runge-kutta-methods

I have a matrix $A$ and a vector $b$. I need to numerically calculate $e^{t A}b$.

That can be seen as the solution of the initial value problem

$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = A y; \;\;\; y(0)=b
$$

Therefore I can use Runge Kutta methods to calculate $e^{t A}b$.

Is it inefficient? What are more efficient ways to compute that?
I suppose Pade approximant should be more efficient. But how much more?

Thanks!

Comment: The usual methods for the computation of the matrix exponential have nothing to do with Runge-Kutta and almost nothing with Padé approximants. Of course it is valid within the error bounds to compute $(e^{hA})^n$ via $s_p(hA)^n$ where $s_p$ is the partial sum of the exponential of degree $p$, or any other approximation of error order $p+1$. It is just in most cases less efficient than the methods that proceed via the eigen-decomposition of $A$.

Comment: Thanks, yet I thought that doing the eigen-decomposition was going to be really expensive for large size matrices (doesn't its cost scale as $N^3$?). Also I was expecting it to be an overkill, since I simply need the product with a single vector. I thought it be worth only if I need to do a large number of those products with the same $A$ but different $b$'s. Could you please direct me towards some efficient numerical methods to perform that operation?

Comment: Regarding the RK method, one matrix-vector product is already $O(N^2)$ for dense matrices. Large matrices in general also tend to have large eigenvectors. These in turn require a small step size for stability and even smaller step size for accurate results. So it depends on several factors, including the type of the desired output, what approach is the most effective. But note that exponential RK methods and operator splitting methods, both using matrix exponentials to enable larger step sizes, exist for a reason.